# Combine multiple line record into one line

Tags: r

I'd like to manipulate data in R as follows, can anybody help please?

Before:

```
Record  Person  Value
1       1       100
1       2       0
1       3       200
2       1       150
2       2       220
```

After:

```
Record  Value
1       {100, 0, 200}
2       {150, 220}
```

Ideally I'd like the final dataset values to be in a list (as opposed to a string), so that I can apply formulas to each value.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `split(df$Value, df$Record)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code

```
dfout <- aggregate(Value~Record, df, toString)
```

or

```
dfout<- aggregate(Value~Record, df,FUN = function(x) x)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Record       Value
1      1 100, 0, 200
2      2    150, 220
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Record = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Person = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), Value = c(100L, 0L, 200L, 150L, 220L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```